# How to reset icon set with AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource?

Tags: taskbar, windows-shell, ipropertystorage

At some point I have set AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource ID to 0 and now program doesn't have an icon in taskbar.

Breaking code:

```
IPropertyStore propStore = GetWindowPropertyStore(hwnd);
using (PROPVARIANT pv = new PROPVARIANT(0)
    propStore.SetValue(PROPERTYKEY.System.AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource, pv);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(propStore);
```

Icon is missing even if I don't set `AppUserModel.ID` when window is opened.

Icons is also missing if I use `AppUserModel.ID` that had icon deleted in the past and even if I try setting a new icon

```
using (PROPVARIANT pv = new PROPVARIANT(@"C:\path\prog.exe"))
    propStore.SetValue(PROPERTYKEY.System.AppUserModel.RelaunchIconResource, pv);
```

I have tried setting icon without specifying `AppUserModel.ID`

**Icon is OK** if I set the `AppUserModel.ID` to a random string, but not if I omit it or use one of old broken `AppUserModel.ID`.

How can I get the icon back for already broken `AppUserModel.ID` or if I don't set `AppUserModel.ID` at all?

I have tried searching registry for program's full path and also for the broken `AppUserModel.ID`.

Comment: Have you tried to set the value to VT_EMPTY? This is how one removes a property from a property store (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propsys/nf-propsys-ipropertystore-setvalue#remarks)

Comment: @SimonMourier VT_EMPTY in all examples I have found is just enum value that equals to 0, which is how I originally broke the icons

Comment: Yes, I know VT_EMPTY value is 0, but it's the official way to remove a property from a property store, and no, it's *not* the same as a PROPVARIANT containing an integer such a 0 (like VT_I4, VT_UI4, VT_I2, VT_UI2, etc.). I don't know how you define PROPVARIANT(0), but I guess it's an integer PROPVARIANT, not the empty PROPVARIANT.

Comment: @SimonMourier it was actually already set to `using (PROPVARIANT pv = new PROPVARIANT((ushort)System.Runtime.InteropServices.VarEnum.VT_EMPTY))`

Comment: I've tested a window property store and a property is indeed deleted when we call SetValue with an empty PROPVARIANT. How is this PROPVARIANT class defined? Where is the (C# I believe) source so we can check what it does exactly?